# Need help recreating a SOAP request in groovy-wslite

Tags: soap, groovy

I had issues getting the most basic of actions working, but finally figured it out.  You can see what I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145944/need-help-converting-php-soap-code-to-groovy-using-groovy-wslite/24149344#24149344)

With that working I'm moving onto the subsequent action and once again running into issues. Here is what the XML SOAP Request looks like which works (generated in PHP)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:ws.company.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="ws.company.com">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:SessionHeader>
            <ns2:sessionId>theLoginSessionID</ns2:sessionId>
        </ns2:SessionHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:triggerCampaignMessage>
            <ns1:campaign>
                <ns1:folderName>theFolder</ns1:folderName>
                <ns1:objectName>theObject</ns1:objectName>
            </ns1:campaign>
            <ns1:recipientData>
                <ns1:recipient>
                    <ns1:listName>
                        <ns1:folderName>theFolder</ns1:folderName>
                        <ns1:objectName>theObject</ns1:objectName>
                    </ns1:listName>
                    <ns1:emailAddress>person@company.com</ns1:emailAddress>
                </ns1:recipient>
                <ns1:optionalData>
                    <ns1:name>order_number</ns1:name>
                    <ns1:value>231</ns1:value>
                </ns1:optionalData>     
            </ns1:recipientData>
        </ns1:triggerCampaignMessage>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The code I am trying to use is this

```
@Grab(group='com.github.groovy-wslite', module='groovy-wslite', version='0.8.0')
import wslite.soap.*

def client = new SOAPClient('https://company/services/WebService')
def response = client.send(SOAPAction:'https://company/services/WebService/') {
    body {
        login('xmlns':'urn:ws.company.com') {[
            username("username"),
            password("password")
            ]}
    }
}
theSession = response.envelope
try {
    response = client.send(SOAPAction:'https://company/services/WebService/') {
        header {
            SessionHeader('xmlns':'urn:ws.company.com') {
                sessionId(theSession)
            }
        }
        body {
            triggerCampaignMessage('xmlns':'urn:ws.company.com') {[
                campaign {[
                    folderName("theFolder"),
                    objectName("theObject")
                ]},
                recipientData {[
                    recipient {[
                        listName {[
                            folderName("theFolder"),
                            objectName("theObject")
                        ]},
                        emailAddress("person@company.com")
                    ]},
                    optionalData {[
                        name("order_number"),
                        value("1234567890")
                    ]}
                ]}
            ]}
        }
    }
} catch (SOAPFaultException sfe) {
    println "fault string :" + sfe.message // faultcode/faultstring for 1.1 or Code/Reason for 1.2
    println "envelope :" + sfe.text    // prints SOAP Envelope
    println "status code :" + sfe.httpResponse.statusCode
    println sfe.fault.detail.text()
}
```

I'm pretty sure that the first send to the login is working since it's the code that works all on it's own and the error message I am receiving is

```
Unexpected subelement {urn:ws.company.com}emailAddress
```

So I'm guessing I'm okay up to that point, but can't figure it out.  Based on the XML that works can anyone help me get my groovy code to work?

EDIT

Here's the response envelope from the login call

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <loginResponse xmlns="urn:ws.company.com">
            <result>
                <sessionId>string here</sessionId>
            </result>
        </loginResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be with `theSession = response.envelope` which will set `theSession` to the entire SOAP response from the first call to `login`.  My guess is that you really need to grab a token value from an element within the login response message, for example:

`theSession = response.loginResponse.result.sessionId.text()`

If you can provide a sample of the result from the call to `login` I can try to provide a more exact answer.

Comment: thanks for your response when I simply do the login call and then println 'envelope: ' + response.envelope it does printout just the sessionID.  Do you still think this is the issue?

Comment: I also just edited the question to include the initial login response envelope

Comment: I updated my answer.  Even though a println only displayed the text value in the xml, the response variable itself was an XmlSlurper GPathResult which I think was causing the problem when using it in the second call.

Comment: Hi John, okay actually found my issue, but that left me with one more now and then I think I have this thing solved.  The issue is that wslite doesn't support session cookies. There's a post on github about working around it, but it's over my head.  Should I update this question or create a new question?

Comment: It seems odd to me that the SOAP service would have a "login" operation that returns a session token, and other operations that take that token in the header, yet still require cookies.  Are you sure cookies are required?It's possible to get the cookies sent by the server and pass them back in subsequent calls, but I don't know you'll get better info here than what you found on github.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm 100% positive it requires the cookie and to pass back the sessionID.  The advice on GitHub is generic 'get the cookie from the headers returned and send in future request headers'.  I can see some data in the response relating to the JESSIONID cookie, but no idea how to retrieve and insert it.

Comment: Hahaha it was your comment on GitHub I was referencing about 'get the cookie from the headers returned and send in future request headers' -- Any advice? LOL

Comment: After calling login you then have to grab any cookies returned, something like def cookies = response.httpResponse.headers['Set-Cookie'] and then you'd set a 'Cookie' header in your subsequent requests.  You can add headers to requests by using the 'headers' and setting it to a map.